# On the Fourier transform of $x \mapsto e^{-|x|}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I am finding Fourier transform quite hard. I am supposed to find the Fourier transform of $$f(x)=e^{-|x|}$$ I tried myself and looked at the solution sheet, but I have some questions.

[image]

1. How come $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\sin(wx)dx = 0$?
2. How come they change the integration $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\cos(wx)dx$ = $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\cos(wx)dx$?

Comment: You have a typo in question 2. The bottom limit in the first integral should be $-\infty$.

Comment: Please separate the statement of the problem from your thoughts / work on it.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your question 1, the integrand is odd so the integral is zero.

For question 2, the LHS lower limit was $-\infty$ not $0$. The integrand is even so the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is $2\times$ the same integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Ah, thank u! but, should it not be $cos(-wx)$ since we had $e^{-iwx}$?

Comment: @Lisa cosine is an even function: $\cos (-\theta )= \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

> howcome $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}\sin(\omega x)\,dx=0$?

notice that if:
$$f(x)=e^{-|x|}\sin(\omega x)$$
then:
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$
i.e. it is an odd function. This means that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0f(x)\,dx=-\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\therefore \int_{-\infty}^0f(x)\,dx+\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=0$$

---

> howcome they change the integration $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\cos(wx)dx$ = $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\cos(wx)dx$

Notice that the integrand is this time an even function i.e. $g(-x)=g(x)$ (also note you made a typo in the lower limit of LHS). This means:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0g(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx\therefore \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dx=2\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$$
Now you just have to do some rearranging:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\cos(\omega x)\,dx=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-|x|}\cos(\omega x)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac 2 \pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-|x|}\cos(\omega x)\,dx$$
and you obtain the next line

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this
$$F(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|} e^{-iwx} dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left (\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{x} e^{-iwx} dx +\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x} e^{-iwx} dx \right)$$
In the first let $x=-y$, then
$$F(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1-iw)y} dy 
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1+iw)x} dx \right)$$

$$\implies F(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{1-iw}+\frac{1}{1+iw}\right)$$ $$ =\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+w^2}$$